# Number of full binary trees is Catalan, What is the number of Binary trees?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, computer-science, catalan-numbers

In exercise 12-4 of "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et.al (third edition), they mention that the number of Binary trees with $n$ nodes is given by the Catalan numbers,

$$b_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}$$

In the Wikipedia article on Catalan numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) however, they say that this is the number of "Full binary trees". Meaning every node has zero or two children.

This seems to be an apparent contradiction. Is this an omission in Cormen's book? Or is the Wikipedia article incorrect? And if $b_n$ is the number of full binary trees with $n$ nodes, what is the number of binary trees? And why should only one of them satisfy the recurrence given in part-a of exercise 12-4:

$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k b_{n-1-k}$$

Comment: [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108) description says "is the number of ordered rooted trees with n nodes, not including the root.", references are given there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted an essential part of the Wikipedia statement: $C_n$ is the count of full binary trees **with $n+1$ leaves**, not with $n$ nodes as in the other statement. So there’s no contradiction; both statements are correct.

Comment: So is it true that the number of full, rooted trees with $n$ nodes is $b_{n+1}$ but the number of rooted trees with $n$ nodes is $b_n$? Can we prove this.

Comment: @RohitPandey: How did you arrive at those statements? The statement in Wikipedia is that the number of full trees with $n$ leaves is $b_{n-1}$, so that differs from what you wrote in two respects ($-1$ instead of $+1$, and leaves instead of nodes).

Comment: @RohitPandey How can there be more trees if you require them to be full? It's the other way around, and it's rather simple, actually. The first point is that you, like I did initially, missed the use of the word "leaf". The full binary trees are measured by the number of _leaves_ that they have.